# WPF: where i can catch application crash event?

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I put this code in my `entry point`:

```
   public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);
            Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

        }

        private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void Dispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And add this code into some `button` click:

```
int num = 10;
int t = 5;
t = t - 5;
int error = num / t;
```

And my application crash but not go into this events.

Comment: I think this answer might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16719157/7026554

Comment: Where i need to put this [STAThread] 
static void Main() ? (i am using WPF)

Comment: Main() in WPF is auto-generated, but you can provide your own:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26890426/7026554

Comment: So how can ii simulate and catch application crash ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try adding this code in App.xaml.cs

```
public App() : base() {
    this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += OnDispatcherUnhandledException;
}

void OnDispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("Unhandled exception occurred: \n" + e.Exception.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

Comment: Ok this works now, i need also to add UnhandledExceptionEventArgs or DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs  is enough ?

Comment: `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` takes care of all unhandled exceptions, `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs` **included**! sorry for the late reply

Comment: So UnhandledExceptionEventArgs  in enough  and no need DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs  ?

Comment: `DispatcherUnhandledException` catches all exceptions on the UI thread. while using it you can call either `DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs` or `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` which includes the former and every other unhandled exception on all threads.

Answer (score 1):

If you run in debug mode then your app will break as soon as you hit an error.
You would need to disable that. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to see the Exception settings window and uncheck some. Remember to turn it back though.

The full list of handlers:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Handling-Unhandled-47492d0b

You can simulate an error just by throwing one.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/exceptions/creating-and-throwing-exceptions